# Qpid Java 6.0.1 vs Qpid JMS vs Qpid Proton

Tags: java, jms, messaging, amqp, qpid

What is difference between Qpid Java 6.0.1 and Qpid JMS 0.9.0 and Qpid Proton?
I am new with JMS and  wanted to implement simple JMS application with Apache Qpid.
Can anyone provide me links to understand it.

Answer (score 7):

The three are quite different beasts.

The [Qpid Java](http://qpid.apache.org/components/java-broker/index.html) project is a Messageing Broker for AMQP that includes support for the 0.9, 0.9.1 and 0.10 AMQP draft specification along with support for the current AMQP v1.0 specification.  Qpid Java does include a JMS client for the older draft specification of AMQP (0.9, 0.9.1 and 0.10.0) but it does not include an AMQP 1.0 JMS client, that is what Qpid JMS is.

The [Qpid JMS project](http://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html) is a stand alone JMS v1.1 client library that speaks AMQP v1.0 and can be used against any AMQP 1.0 compliant broker such as Qpid Java, AcitveMQ, Qpid C++ broker etc.  The Qpid JMS client is built on top of Qpid Proton.

The [Qpid Proton](http://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) project is an AMQP 1.0 based project that provides clients and a protocol engine for message based applications to use to communicate using AMQP.  The project includes clients in a number of languages including C, C++, Python and Java to name a few.  Besides the clients the project provides a core protocol engine that can be used to implement your own AMQP clients or server applications using a variety of programming languages.  As mentioned above the Qpid JMS client uses the Proton protocol engine to implement its AMQP 1.0 protocol support and maps JMS behaviours on top of that protocol.

Which of these projects you use depends on what your use case is and what you are needing to implement.  Each project has documentation and examples that you can review to get a better understanding of the scope of features each provides.

Comment: Thanks Tim Bish for your explanation.

Comment: What is difference between APIs qpid-jms-client:0.51.0 and qpid-client:6.3.4?

Comment: what is activemq-client ? where does it sit in this eco space

Comment: Surprisingly activemq-client would be the ActiveMQ client, namely a JMS 1.1 client for ActiveMQ